# How to draw multiple overlay contour plot in R

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I have a list (cm) of 9 5x5 matrices which I would like to visualise using an overlay contour plot of different colours for each of the 9 methods. Currently I can draw individual matrix using perspective plot

```
persp(w1, w2, cm[[1]], theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

where a and b are the two weight values i.e independent variables coming from

```
w1 <- seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
w2 <- seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
```

the individual values of each matrix are returned by the function (w1*x+w2*y+w3*z) where w3 = 1-(w1+w2)

For instance:

```
> cm[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.5032247 0.4924513 0.4816779 0.4709045 0.4601311
[2,] 0.4944491 0.4836757 0.4729023 0.4621289 0.4513555
[3,] 0.4856735 0.4749001 0.4641267 0.4533533 0.4425799
[4,] 0.4768979 0.4661245 0.4553511 0.4445777 0.4338043
[5,] 0.4681223 0.4573489 0.4465755 0.4358021 0.4250287
```

#### ----- Code ----

```
dataset <- read.table("composite_metric.log", header=T, sep=" ")

j = 1
df <- data.frame(cm = numeric(27))
while(j <= 27){  
  df$cm[j] <- mean(dataset[,j])
  j = j + 1
}

df <- t(df)

cm.i <- function(w.lb, w.dti, row, col){
  return(df[row,col]*w.lb + df[row,(col+9)]*(1-(w.lb+w.dti)) + df[row,(col+18)]*w.dti)
}

w_lb <- seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
w_dti <- seq(0.1, 0.5, 0.1)
cm <- list()

col = 1
while(col <= 9){
  cm[[col]] = outer(w_lb, w_dti, cm.i, 1, col)
  col = col + 1
}

persp(w_lb, w_dti, cm[[1]], theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
filled.contour(w_lb, w_dti, cm[[1]])
```

Comment: If you want to overlay contours then use `contour` followed by a second call that use `add=TRUE` with a different color. Worked examples offered if you provide reproducible data.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat could you kindly explain. I was looking at the documentation for contour but didn't get how to use add=TRUE. And when I am using `filled.contour(w_lb, w_dti, cm[[1]])` command it gives a plot with different colours. But what I wanted is different overlaid contours with different colours for cm[[2]], cm[[3]] ... .

Comment: _That_) is the reason we ask everyone to provide code. You had said _nothing_ about using `filled.contour`. I was talking about `contour` ... different. Edit your question if you have more specifics. Data #and# code

Comment: My apologies for this. I am very new to R and only learning for couple of days. Thanks for pointing out this to me.